# Site1 wordpress website redirect to other site2 in my same server

Tags: redirect, ssl

I am using Alibaba Cloud Server Ubuntu 18.04 and control panel is VestaCP.
I have got a WordPress website [www.site1.com](http://www.site1.com) . However, after I install SSL via really simple ssl plugin.
Now, I cannot access [www.site1.com](http://www.site1.com) and [www.site1.com/wp-admin](http://www.site1.com/wp-admin) .
It redirect to my other wordpress website in same server which https://site2.com.
Both domains are point to my server.

1.) I want get back my  [www.site1.com](http://www.site1.com) and [www.site1.com/wp-admin](http://www.site1.com/wp-admin) and not redirect to my other site in my server.

How can I fix this? I am not sure what are the issues.

Comment: It is unclear with this short information. Please provide us with more of the plugin and server configuration etc.

Comment: Hello and welcome to WordPress Development. As your question stands, there is not enough information to provide an answer. Not without guessing and making unfounded assumptions about your setup. You will need to edit your question with more specificity. However, I expect that your question may be better suited to your cloud hosting provider or to VestaCP as I'm fairly sure this is a server config issue to do with your SSL setup and maybe DNS (those are guesses).